# Store a list of values in Django keys with a single submit

Tags: django, django-views

I can get the values of all fields as below in the **views.py**

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    teacher_get = request.POST.get('teacher')
    department_get = request.POST.get('department')
    subject_get = request.POST.get('subject')
    semester_get = request.POST.get('semester')
    answers = [v for q, v in request.POST.items() if q.startswith('question_')]
```

Now I want to store these values in the Student class which most of its fields are foreign key.

```
class Student(models.Model):
    teacher = models.ForeignKey(Teacher, on_delete=models.CASCADE)   
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    subject = models.ForeignKey(Subject, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    department = models.ForeignKey(Department, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    semester = models.ForeignKey(Semester, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    answer = models.SmallIntegerField(choices=RATING_CHOICES, default=1)
```

For example, a student login to the form page and start answering questions, at the end when he/she clicks submit button, All questions have their answer. In other words, after submission I have for example 15 Student objects which each object belongs to a specific question.
My form looks like this:

```
    <form action="{% url 'question'%}" method="POST">
      {% csrf_token %}
      <select name="teacher">
        {% for teacher in teacher %}
          <option value="{{ teacher.name }}">{{ teacher.name }}</option>
        {% endfor %}
      </select>
    </div>

<div>
  <select name="department">
    {% for department in department %}
      <option value="{{ department.name }}">{{ department.name }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
  </select>
</div>

<div>
  <select name="semester">
    {% for semester in semester_choices %}
      <option value="{{ semester.0 }}">{{ semester.1 }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
  </select>
</div>

<div>
  <select name="subject">
    {% for subject in subject %}
      <option value="{{ subject.name }}">{{ subject.name }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
  </select>
</div>

  {% for question in question %}
      <ol>{{ question.question }}</ol>
      
      {% for choice in rating_choices %}
       <input type="radio" name="question_{{question.id}}" value="{{choice.0}}">{{choice.1}}
      {% endfor %}

      {% endfor %} <br>

  <input type="submit" value="Vote">
</form>
```

I tried assigning stored value in object (Teacher.objects.create(name=teacher_get)), which results in creating a new object in Teacher class.

[image: In the admin for each question I have to save an object.]

[image: in the html it is like this:]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create Django model form, then use it to store the data:

```
# form
from django.forms import ModelForm    
from .models import Student


class StudentForm(ModelForm):
     class Meta:
         model = Student
         fields = '__all__'

# view
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = StudentForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
```

But you need to make some changes in html template for the form, to change attribute of `value` to primary key of respective model:

```
<select name="teacher">
    {% for teacher in teacher %}
      <option value="{{ teacher.pk }}">{{ teacher.name }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
  </select>
</div>

<div>
  <select name="department">
    {% for department in department %}
      <option value="{{ department.pk }}">{{ department.name }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
  </select>
</div>

<div>
  <select name="semester">
    {% for semester in semester_choices %}
      <option value="{{ semester.pk }}">{{ semester.1 }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
  </select>
</div>

<div>
  <select name="subject">
    {% for subject in subject %}
      <option value="{{ subject.pk }}">{{ subject.name }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
  </select>
</div>
```

For more information, please check [ModelForm documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelform)